# How to avoid AngularFire syncing old data from device waking up from sleep?

Tags: firebase, angularfire

I'm using AngularFire 1.1.3 for a collaborative waitlisting application. This works great when all clients are online, but I've found that when one returns from sleep and reconnects, it's stale view of the world seems to overwrite the more up-to-date data on the other clients. The issue has been reproduced on different Android and iOS devices  as well.

## Update

I believe this has to do with $interval as I was unable to reproduce issue with interval removed.

## Steps to reproduce

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gppsu5bv/26/)

1. Open JS Fiddle on Client 1 (any device)
2. Open JS Fiddle on Client 2 (iOS device)
3. Put Client 2 to sleep (let it sleep >1 min)
4. On Client 1, add or remove a couple of people in the fiddle waitlist.
5. Wake up Client 2. Notice that the changes made in 4) did not take effect.
6. Notice that on Client 1 the changes in 4) have now disappeared and reverted to the previous state.

## Implementation details

I have Firebase data in this format, using `set()` instead of `push()` to key on phone numbers.

```
{"waiting" : [
    "1651234567" : {
        name: "John",
        phone: "+16509606871",
        email: "john@doe.com"
        },
    "16512345679" : {
        name: "Jane",
        phone: "+16512345679",
        email: "jane@doe.com"
        }
    ]
}
```

I bind the data to the Angular scope using the ControllerAs syntax as such:

```
list.waitingGuests = $firebaseArray(new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL + "guests/" + WAITLIST_ID + "/waiting"));
```

I then iterate over the array using ng-repeat:

```
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="guest in list.guests">
    </tr>
    ...
</tbody>
```

What I'd like to learn is what I can do to help ensure the correct, newest data wins in the merge process when a client comes back online and what I may be doing wrong today.

Comment: A client overwriting the data in the database with stale data is unlikely in this scenario. But since your code doesn't show any writing operation, it's impossible to say more. Can you set up a [minimal reproduction of the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in a site like jsfiddle/jsbin and post the code here?

Comment: Hi Frank! I created a JS Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/gppsu5bv/26 and added steps to reproduce above. While doing so, I realize that the issue most likely is related to the $interval loop and/or angular.forEach() iteration that is run to refresh the guests wait duration.

Comment: Yeah, that fiddle is "a bit more involved" than the code you included in your question. If you're running updates in an interval, you're bound to run into race conditions where the (chronological) last write to arrive at the server wins. If that is not what you want, you should probably be [using a transaction](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/saving-data.html#section-transactions).

Comment: One other safeguard you could use here is to add a timestamp to the records. Then you can use a security rule to enforce that when records are added, the timestamp is always greater than the current (i.e. in the timestamp field: `".validate": "newData.isNumeric() && !data.exists() || newData.val() >= data.val()"`). Note that this doesn't invalidate Puf's suggestions; fixing the race condition is paramount.

Comment: That's a good idea. Thanks both, Kato and Frank.